# Array map equivalent for GraphQL query

Tags: graphql

I was wondering if it is possible to reduce the return payload of this query Result:

```json
{
  "nodes": [
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "typescript"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "discord"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "discord-bot"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "discordjs"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "discordjs-commando"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "mbti-personality"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "mbti"
      }
    },
    {
      "topic": {
        "name": "typeorm"
      }
    }
  ]
}
```

Into something like this:

```json
{
  "nodes": ["typescript", "discord", "discord-bot", "discordjs", "discordjs-commando", "mbti-personality", "mbti", "typeorm"]
}
```

I find it very verbose and unnecessary

I am not the owner of the API. So that concerns only the **query**. (It the Github's GraphQL API)

I'm new to GraphQL and don't undestand the principles yet, so I don't know the terms to search for.

Comment: Unlikely. You have to play by the rules of the api owner's schema, and the purpose of a schema is to have a concrete data structure.

Comment: Makes sense, thanks for your information !